# Can I define a function inside print() function or regular if-else statements & not using Ternary Operators in Python?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, printing

I get an error as described below when I use regular syntax of if-else statement inside the print function in the below code block,

```
def to_smash(total_candies):
"""Return the number of leftover candies that must be smashed after distributing
the given number of candies evenly between 3 friends.

>>> to_smash(91)
1
"""

print("Splitting", total_candies, 
(def plural_or_singular(total_candies):
    if total_candies>1:
        return "candies"
    else:
        return "candy"),
plural_or_singular(total_candies))
return total_candies % 3

to_smash(1)
to_smash(15)
```

####################################################################################

```
 Output:
File "<ipython-input-76-b0584729b150>", line 10
    (def plural_or_singular(total_candies):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I meant by regular if-else statements,

```
if total_candies>1:
        return "candies"
    else:
        return "candy")
```

Same statement using Ternary operators,

```
print("Splitting", total_candies, "candy" if total_candies == 1 else "candies")
```

Comment: Are you aware of ``lambda``? Why do you even want to do this?

Comment: You can use `lambda` expressions, although lambda bodies are limited to expressions.  You can get if/else functionality by using the `a if c else b` ternary operator.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  No, I'm a beginner just stated tutorial of python on Kaggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def to_smash(total_candies):
    print("Splitting", total_candies, (lambda total_candies: "candies" if total_candies > 1 else "candy")(total_candies))        
    return total_candies % 3

to_smash(1)
to_smash(15)
```

However, note that Python isn't as versatile as Javascript in regards to passing functions -- `lambda` has its limitations, specifically being *only* a one-liner function. I would instead recommend just defining your function outside of the print statement all together.

```
def to_smash(total_candies):
    def plural_or_singular(total_candies):
        if total_candies>1:
            return "candies"
        else:
            return "candy"

    print("Splitting", total_candies, plural_or_singular(total_candies))
    return total_candies % 3

to_smash(1)
to_smash(15)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. Just one last question before I mark it complete.
So, it's just incorrect syntax if I define a function inside print() or use the regular version of if-else statements as defined?

Comment: My pleasure. Make sure to mark an answer that solves your case to keep the forum clean. Stay well.

Comment: @BelalNoor `def` is not an expression, so you can't use it to define functions in an expression context (such as an argument to `print`).  The best you can do in an expression context is to use a `lambda` expression, which defines a function using expression syntax.  That's why multiple people mentioned it.